# Is there Carriage Return, Line Break constant in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access

A simple question, doing my head in...

I have a large access database to clean up.

Is there a system constant for a line break in Access (Like VB's VBCrLf)?

If not,I guess I'll just have to use Chr(13) + Chr(10)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In VBA, `vbCrLf` is the line break constant (along with `vbCr` and `vbLf`).

In a string data column, it's `Chr(13) + Chr(10)` (which is what `vbCrLf` is defined as).

Answer (score 9):

While **vbCrLf**, **vbCr** and **vbLf** exist, it is better to use **vbNewLine**.

Why?
1) Because vbNewLine will output the newline sequence for the current operating system (which may change) vs the other three which will put out only the carriage return and linefeed characters.
2) Because it is less cryptic. Using vbCr is just about as bad as chr(13)

The logical comeback is... come on when is MS ever going to change the newline, they'd be nuts. As it is, portability. There are already .Net ports to unix/linux and there is no reason that MS access can't be emulated there either. (E.g., perhaps in Wine)

**Edit**

A parallel to this idea would be using \n in C and C++ vs entering \f\r. \n will give you the native newline sequence (even if you flip from Unix to Windows to Mac to Vax to QNX). No conditional statements, no edits. It just works.

Comment: What, exactly, does .NET have to do with Access? I have to say, I think your suggestion is crazy. :)

Comment: .Net is just a parallel example. I presume that you might be able to run a MS access app in Wine (no idea, but the philosophy is the same).

Comment: +1.  This is a valid point.  There is usually no good reason to not code for optimal portability -- now or in the future.

Comment: This answer does not address the original question. If it provided an equivalent to vbNewline or \n for use in Access/JET SQL it might be useful.