# How to identify a hidden carriage return character in a UNIX text file over VBA?

Tags: excel, unix, text-files, ascii, vba

I have an application written in Excel/VBA which reads text files written in UNIX. These files consist in Finite Element Modeling simulation settings, where each line in a 20k+ text file is an individual setting. My application searches for a particular Setting and returns them to the user in plain English. A particular line could look like this:

```
model.settings.excitation.modes=50
```

So far, this line of code worked to find the text between the '=' sign and the end of line

```
InStr(1, FileContents, vbLf)
```

where FileContents is the whole text file after the '=' symbol.

Something somewhere upstream of my application has changed the assumed carriage return character 'vbLf' cannot be found, however it is clearly there when viewing it in Notepad++. My application depends on finding this carriage return, and now it doesn't work.

I have tried using :

```
Asc(Mid(AdsFileContentsX, 3, 1))
```

to isolate the carriage return character but I end up with a character from the next line, so that doesn't work either.

I tried all of the below as well

```
InStr(1, FileContents, vbLf)
InStr(1, FileContents, vbCrLf)
InStr(1, FileContents, vbCr)
InStr(1, FileContents, vbNewLine)
InStr(1, FileContents, Chr(10))
InStr(1, FileContents, Chr(13))
```

but none of these found the carriage return character.

Any suggestions on how to identify the carriage return character being used in a textfile?

*edited to include everything I have tried

Comment: Normally it just requires trial and error with one of these: vbCrLf, vbCr vbLf or vbNewLine see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556978/is-there-carriage-return-line-break-constant-in-ms-access

Comment: Why don't you use RegEx instead?

Comment: None of these have worked. I also tried with CHR(10) and CHR(13).

Comment: I think you're going to have to run a loop and print out the ascii value of each character. It would be useful to know what that 'end of line' character is, so if you could add the ascii values from a sample line of data to your question then we might be able to help a bit more.

Answer (score 4):

You can test for either *ASCII10* or *ASCII13*:

```
Sub hskdjfh()
    v = Range("A1").Value
    If InStr(1, v, Chr(10)) > 0 Or InStr(1, v, Chr(13)) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "got a return"
    Else
        MsgBox "no return"
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Here is one way to determine exactly what is in a cell:

```
Sub WhatsInThere()
    Dim s As String, L As Long
    Dim msg As String, i As Long

    msg = ""
    s = Range("A1").Text
    L = Len(s)

    For i = 1 To L
        msg = msg & vbCrLf & i & vbTab & Mid(s, i, 1) & vbTab & AscW(Mid(s, i, 1))
    Next i

    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

In this case I placed an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> just after the **i** in cell **A1**:

[image]

Comment: @W5ALIVE  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: God bless you. I was going nuts why my string wouldn't split. Your solution helped me identify which carriage string was split by.

Comment: You did not mention which method you use to read in the lines. If you use FilesystemObject.Readline , it will read the line and not return the record separator character it used to find enad-of-line. Once the record is inside Excel, that separator character is gone.
If the file had Windows style newlines, there would be 2 separator characters: CR+LF. If it was *nix style, there would only be LF. If it came from a Mac, only CR would be used. 
This affects what's in the lines pulled into Excel. You can use other methods than Readline to read the lines that give more control over the process.

Comment: @charlesross  You are correct.  The author of the question did not indicate how the data was imported. I only addressed actions **after** the import.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure there is a bug in VBA,  i have 013 010 013 and vba cannot see it, it only sees it as 013 010,

removing 013 010 from the string using replace ,  then checking the result there is THEN another 013  , so it is taking 2 lines of code to remove it due to this bug